# Is there a data structure for storing boolean expressions?

Tags: java

I need to store Boolean expressions like this:

```
x1 AND x2 AND x3 OR (x4 AND x5) AND (NOT x6)
```

Each `x` variable is a Boolean expression like `==` or `!=` with values. The problem is to store nested `AND` and `OR` clauses (inside themselves and/or inside each other) and wrap them with `NOT`. The wrapping depth can be very deep.

Does the Java SDK have data structure for these expressions?

Comment: There is no such standard data structure.

Comment: Boolean expressions are, after all, mathematical expressions, and to deal with them properly I would think you would need a symbolic manipulation library, as Java (and most programming languages) are only going to handle numeric manipulation out of the box. Google suggests: https://github.com/yuemingl/SymJava

Comment: How did you do this?

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 the functional interface `Predicate<T>` is the way to go.

Here are the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

And here are various [examples](http://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/java-8-java-util-function-predicate-tutorial-with-examples/).

So in your use case it will be something as follows:

```
public static Predicate<Integer> equals(Integer compare) {
    return i -> i.equals(compare);
}

public static Predicate<Integer> complex() {
    return equals(1).and(equals(2)).and(equals(3)).or(equals(4).and(equals(5))).and(equals(6).negate());
}
```

Remember — only Java 8 onwards!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use jexl (http://commons.apache.org/jexl/)

```
JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
    jexl.setSilent(true);
    jexl.setLenient(true);

    Expression expression = jexl.createExpression("(a || b && (c && d))");
    JexlContext jexlContext = new MapContext();

    //b and c and d should pass
    jexlContext.set("b",true);
    jexlContext.set("c",true);
    jexlContext.set("d",true);

    assertTrue((Boolean)expression.evaluate(jexlContext));

    jexlContext = new MapContext();

    //b and c and NOT d should be false
    jexlContext.set("b",true);
    jexlContext.set("c",true);

    //note this works without setting d to false on the context
    //because null evaluates to false

    assertFalse((Boolean)expression.evaluate(jexlContext));
```

Example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736684/boolean-expression-evaluation-in-java?rq=1)

ps: It is not included in standard sdk but quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Predicate {...}
class AndPredicate extends Predicate {
  private Predicate[] conjuncts;
  ...
}
class OrPredicate extends Predicate {
  private Predicate[] disjuncts;
  ...
}
class NotPredicate extends Predicate {
  Predicate negated;
  ...
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The promlems is - not to reinvent the wheel and support it. There is a lot data structures likr Maps, Lists, Sets, and no one for boolean expressions?

Comment: Such data structures will typically be found in compiler technology.  You could search for a compiler that exposes its internal data structures as a public library.  Good luck with that.