# Spring Spel for roles

Tags: spring, expression, spring-el

I have a custom requirement where I want to decide if an API can be accessed depending on certain roles. I am using Spring framework.
I want to support something like this:

```
1. (R1 || R2) && (R3 || R4)  
2. (R1) || (R2 && R3)
```

where `R` represents a role. `||` and `&&` are logical operators denoting `or` and `and` respectively.
This expression should be evaluated against an input array of roles.
So if the input array is [R2, R4], then the first expression evaluates to true and second expression evaluates to false.

I found something similar using SPEL but instead of `R` which can be any String like *customer*, *employee*, etc, they are using boolean expressions value like `true` or `6 == 6`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem using the following:

1. I used SpEL as provided by Spring.
2. SpEL supports property replacement.

Code for replacement:

```
Inventor tesla = new Inventor("Nikola Tesla");
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("name == Nikola Tesla");
String name = (String) exp.getValue(tesla);
```

Here, the `name` property will be replaced by Nikola Tesla.
This should be used when the name property has different value each time the expression is evaluated.
If the value of `name` property is the same every time, consider using `EvaluationContext`.

Now talking about the boolean expressions, you will have to compulsorily substitute values for properties, because in above example, property `name` can take `null` as the default value, but a string role can't take `true` or `false` without substitution.
 And let's suppose that the SpEL contains some roles which I am not aware of, I won't be able to replace them with `true` and `false`. To solve this, I used something similar to @PreAuthorize which has the method `hasRole()`.

Code for reference:

```
String roles =  "(hasRole('admin') or hasRole('superAdmin')) and hasRole('modifier')"
Expression roleExpression = parser.parseExpression(roles);
StandardEvaluationContext roleContext = new StandardEvaluationContext(new SpelHelper());
roleContext.addPropertyAccessor(new MapAccessor()); // this line might be useless
Boolean hasCorrectRole = roleExpression.getValue(roleContext, Boolean.class);


class SpelHelper {
     public boolean hasRole(String role) {
          // some logic like current user roles have the role passed as argument
          return true;
     }
}
```

Full documentation at: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Also, refer [Boolean Expression Evaluation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736684/boolean-expression-evaluation-in-java)
This answer suggests using JEXL and the answer will give you a fair idea what to do to replace properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use method security based on roles with SpEL.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_A') or hasRole('ROLE_B')")
public void yourMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i have a custom requirement, can not go with preauthorize